# How to split a list into 2 separate list based on a filed in the parent list with linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Here is the linq that generates a list

```
var query = (from vinfo in vQuery 
            join Add in _db.Addresses on vinfo.Id equals Add.vId
            select new AddressLabels
            {
              Id = vinfo.Id,
              Name = vinfo.Name,
              Address1 = Add.Address1,
              Address2 = Add.Address2,
              ZipCode = Add.ZipCode,
              City = Add.City,
              Country = Add.Country,
              Contact1 = Add.Contact1,
              Contact2 = Add.Contact2
            });
```

In the above list, there is possibility that both contact1 and contact2 are same. 
When Contact1 is not equal to contact2, i have to generate 2 separate list for each of the 2 contacts  from the above list. 
The lists will have the same data as the parent list but one list will have contact1 and the other list will have contact2
This is what i am looking at.

List1:

```
Id
Name
Address1
Address2
ZipCode
City
Country
Contact1
```

List2:

```
Id
Name
Address1
Address2
ZipCode
City
Country
Contact2
```

Kindly help

Comment: First, why doesn't have to be done with Linq?

Comment: Not necessarily linq. How else should it be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check if your list has items with same contacts
if (!query.Any(a => a.Contact1.Equals(a.Contact2)))
{
    return query;
}

// Else, create two new lists
var itemsWithSameContacts = query.Where(a => a.Contact1.Equals(a.Contact2));

var firstList = itemsWithSameContacts.Select(a => new AddressLabels
{
    Id = a.Id,
    Name = a.Name,
    Address1 = a.Address1,
    Address2 = a.Address2,
    ZipCode = a.ZipCode,
    City = a.City,
    Country = a.Country,
    Contact1 = a.Contact1,
}).ToList();

var secondList = itemsWithSameContacts.Select(a => new AddressLabels
{
    Id = a.Id,
    Name = a.Name,
    Address1 = a.Address1,
    Address2 = a.Address2,
    ZipCode = a.ZipCode,
    City = a.City,
    Country = a.Country,
    Contact2 = a.Contact2,
}).ToList();

// If you want these lists also to have contacts 
// which don't have same contacts, then you can also
var itemsWithNotSameContacts = query.Where(a => !a.Contact1.Equals(a.Contact2));
firstList.AddRange(itemsWithNotSameContacts);
secondList.AddRange(itemsWithNotSameContacts);
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking at the last part of your answer, that is, when contacts are not same. How do i do a foreach loop on the list for check to generate the separate 2 lists ONLY when the contacts are not same.? else have only one list.

Comment: Updated. Check the first line.